# Replace values of one hash with keys of second hash when their values are equal

Tags: ruby, hash, comparison

long time appreciator of the Ruby Gurus first time question.

I have two hashes.

```
hash1 = {"a" =>1, "b"=> 2, "c" => 3}

hash2 = {"f" =>1, "g"=> 2, "h" => 3, "i"=>2, "j"=>1}
```

I want to replace the values of the of the second hash with the keys of the first hash when their values are equal something like:

```
hash2 = {"f"=>"a", "g"=>"b", "h"=>"c", "i"=>"b", "j"=>"a"}
```

The order doesn't matter at all.

Comment: So, what's the problem with implementing that?

Comment: How do i compare the hashes and replace the values in hash2 with the keys in hash1 when their values match? I'm not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: Why on earth do you want to do this?

Comment: It was used as part of a script to find IP's that existed on more than one server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hash1_inverted = hash1.invert
hash3 = hash2.map { |k, v| [k, hash1_inverted[v]] }.to_h
#=> {"f"=>"a", "g"=>"b", "h"=>"c", "i"=>"b", "j"=>"a"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do as below :

```
hash1 = {:a =>1, :b=> 2, :c => 3} 
hash2 = {:f =>1, :g=> 2, :h => 3, :i=>2, :j=>1}
hash2.each_with_object({}){|(k,v),h| h[k]=hash1.key(v)}
# => {:f=>:a, :g=>:b, :h=>:c, :i=>:b, :j=>:a}
```

or

```
hash1 = {:a =>1, :b=> 2, :c => 3} 
nw_hsh = hash1.invert
hash2 = {:f =>1, :g=> 2, :h => 3, :i=>2, :j=>1}
hash2.each_with_object({}){|(k,v),h| h[k]=nw_hsh[v]}
# => {:f=>:a, :g=>:b, :h=>:c, :i=>:b, :j=>:a}
```

Comment: Just be aware that you are searching through `hash1` on every iteration.

Comment: @Stefan I followed this *I want to replace the values of the of the second hash with the keys of the first hash when their values are equal*.

Comment: And the result is correct. However, you basically have a loop (`hash1.key`) inside a loop (`hash2.map`). This can be slow for large hashes.

Comment: @Stefan I have updated.... :) Thanks for commenting

Comment: Still two nested loops :) Set up two hashes with 100,000 entries each and compare your solution to tokland's answer